# Подключение скрипта в index.html react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Как подключить скрипт написанный мною к index.html в react. Подключаю как обычно:

`<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>`

выпадают ошибки, типа

***Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html***.

Или это как-то по-другому делать надо?

Comment: Попробуйте type="text/javascript"

Comment: @Грузчик тогда импорты/экспорты не сработают

Comment: Попробовала засунуть все скрипты в папку public, но перестали работать ипорты бибилиотек , а снаружи выпадает эта ошибка, не знаю что делать :(